# Vim; Shortcut to add comment at beginning of line

Tags: vim, vimrc, vi

When I code, I tend to execute the following manually a lot after having selected multiple lines of code.

```
:'<,'>s/^/#/
```

I want to add this to my .vimrc but I am having troubles making it work. The intention is to be able to select a set of lines and then press mapleader c and vim will add an extra # at the beginning of all selected lines.

```
1 " Key mapping.                                                                                                                                                      
2 let mapleader = ","
...
141 nmap <silent> <leader>c :<'>'s/^/#/<CR>
```

Line 141 seems to just delete the selected lines and I am having troubles seeing why this is. Any ideas what I am doing wrong or what I can change to get this to work?

Comment: You could also consider the NerdCommenter plugin btw., which can do this and more: https://github.com/scrooloose/nerdcommenter

Comment: @miyalys, I am quite satisfied with the setup I have a this very moment and I wish only to add that specific option. I feel that adding a feature rich plugin just to get me this is a bit overkill. Thank you for the suggestion though.

Comment: Alright, I'm not sure why you're using an `nmap` if you want to select the lines in `visual mode` first, but if you still want to select the lines first in visual mode I have a suggestion for vimrc, however it seems I can't get it to work with <leader>c for some reason (maybe <leader>c will work for you):
`vmap <silent> t :s/^/#/<CR>:let @/ = ""<CR>`. If this solves your problem okay I'll write it up as an answer.

Comment: @Mogget,  in line 141 `<'>'` should be `'<,'>` (wrong order and missin ",");  also define it for visual mode (`vmap ...`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an exact replica of the line @miyalys gave in a comment and it work exactly as I want it to.

```
vmap <silent> t :s/^/#/<CR>:let @/ = ""<CR>
```

He says he could not get it to work with c, but I got it to work with that character.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:  it does a block insert while in visual mode

```
vmap <silent> <leader>c :norm i#<ESC>
```